# iOS Mapbox Custom Marker Will Not Appear

Tags: ios, mapbox

Custom Marker Image will not appear only default marker appears in it's place.

In ViewWillAppear:

```
RMPointAnnotation *annotation3 = [[RMPointAnnotation alloc] initWithMapView:parkMap coordinate:coordinate andTitle:title];
[parkMap addAnnotation:annotation3];
```

---

```
- (RMMapLayer *)mapView:(RMMapView *)mapView layerForAnnotation:(RMAnnotation *)annotation
{
    if (annotation.isUserLocationAnnotation)
        return nil;

    RMMarker *marker;

        marker = [[RMMarker alloc] initWithUIImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"square_small.png"]];

    marker.canShowCallout = YES;

    return marker;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the docs and don't use `RMPointAnnotation`.

> If you wish to customize the layer appearance in more detail, you should instead create an RMAnnotation and configure its layer directly. Providing a layer manually for instances of RMPointAnnotation will not have any effect.

https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-ios-sdk/blob/509fa7df46ebd654d130ab2f530a8e380bf2bd59/MapView/Map/RMPointAnnotation.h#L33

Comment: Thanks it was just the "PointAnnotation" typo - turns out i had RMAnnotation in every other project, eyes couldn't pick up that typo. Been staring at it for hours. Thanks again.